# WooCommerce CSV Exports - Characters displaying incorrectly in Excel

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, export-to-csv

We have a problem with non standard characters being displayed in Excel after being exported as CSV (using All Export) from WooCommerce. Example below:

[image]

However if you open the same file in Notepad, you can see that the characters are actually being exported correctly:

[image]

On [this page](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/umlaute-special-characters-in-export-files/) I found that the exported file might be missing something which tells Excel to display the characters correctly, and they provided the below code to fix the issue with their particular plugin.

```
add_filter( 'tablepress_export_data', 'tablepress_add_bom_to_csv_exports', 10, 4 );
function tablepress_add_bom_to_csv_exports( $export_data, $table, $export_format, $csv_delimiter ) {
  if ( 'csv' === $export_format ) {
    $export_data = "\xEF\xBB\xBF" . $export_data;
  }
  return $export_data;
}
```

Is there a way to modify this code to work with All Export, or with all exports in general, to fix the issue? The above example is German but the file contains all sorts of languages (as we ship globally).

Thanks

Comment: Can you check the excel file Character Sat and language setting. I am facing same problem while export German language post. I solve it by character sat changes.

Comment: I suspect the following link to be the answer to your question; that is, specific program to such as excel require specific settings ; https://www.webtoffee.com/how-to-save-csv-excel-file-as-utf-8-encoded/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure encoding is UTF-8, unicode which supports almost all languages, make sure to change the font that contains all these glyphs for your language.

Comment: Where/how can I check that WordPress is set to export in UTF-8? The database says 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' in phpMyAdmin. The reports are distributed to lots of people at the client, so I can't ask them all to update their computer settings (and they wouldn't know how).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem but not in wordpress, but in Java/ Spring Webapplication by adding the **UTF-8 BOM** prior writing the content to the CSV. This "helps" Excel to understand that the .csv is UTF-8 encoded and thus displays "Umlauts" correctly.

If you need Code examples in Java just ask and I will add them here.

Answer (score -1):

To resolve this issue make the CSV/Excel file into a UTF-8 encoded format. [Read more](https://www.webtoffee.com/how-to-save-csv-excel-file-as-utf-8-encoded/)

Comment: Opening the CSV in Excel and saving as UTF-8 makes it worse, as opening the saved file in Excel is the same as before and opening it Notepad now shows the funny characters instead of the original data as before: https://i.postimg.cc/DywW55Zd/Capture.png